# How to pick animation image from UIImagepicker and add it to UIimageview and upload it

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, animated-gif

I have .gif images in my gallery,I want to upload this gif image using Alamofire,I was able to upload .png,jpg,jpeg image ,but when I try to upload gif image it is uploading as a normal image.

Please find my code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{

    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

    //userDefaultsObj.setValue("", forKey: "imageURL")
    let imageName = imageURL.lastPathComponent
    let imagenamearray = imageName?.components(separatedBy: ".")
    self.Imageextension = (imagenamearray?.last)!.lowercased()
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

    var resizedImg = self.imageResizeFunction(resizeImage: chosenImage)


    let array1 = [UInt8](tmpImage!)
    print("Resized Value:\(array1.count/1024)")

    if (self.Imageextension == "gif")
    {
      selectedimgview.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }else
    {
    selectedimgview.image = resizedImg//chosenImage
    }
    selectedimgview.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

code uploading using Alamofire

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        if imagepresent
        {
            if(imageextension == "jpg")
            {
                multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgparameters["fileName"] as! UIImage, 0.5)!, withName: "file", fileName: "swift_file.\(imageextension)", mimeType: "image/\(imageextension)")
            }
            else if(imageextension == "gif")
            {

                multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgparameters["fileName"] as! UIImage)!, withName: "file", fileName: "swift_file.\(imageextension)", mimeType: "image/\(imageextension)")
            }
            else
            {
                multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgparameters["fileName"] as! UIImage)!, withName: "file", fileName: "swift_file.\(imageextension)", mimeType: "image/\(imageextension)")
            }

        }

        for (key, value) in postparams {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    }, to:requestURL,method : methodType,headers : Header)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                self.handleResponse(response: response, completionBlockX: completionBlock)

                print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request

            }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
            //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }
```

The above give is the code for picking Image from gallery and uploading it to the backend ,This code is perfectly working for .png,.jpg,.jpeg bit not for .gif when upload .gif image it is showing as a normal image.

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: The problem is that you are saying `as! UIImage`. A UIImage cannot be an animated gif.

Comment: @matt thanks for your response instead os as! image what we have to use

Comment: You need to upload the original gif data.

Comment: how to get the gif data from gallery

Answer (score 1):

Back when you said

```
let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
```

you had the original gif data on disk. That is what you want to upload.

Comment: How to add url to imageview and how to convert in to data while uploading

Comment: Listen to what I said in my answer. There is nothing to convert. The URL is the data on disk. Upload it.